# I am trying to calculate a percentage in my sql statement which gives a wrong answer

Tags: sql, sum, percentage

This is my sql statement. The sum of callers total is: `322` and the sum of the other four is: `9966`. `322 / 9966 = 0,32`... Now my problem is that in sql it gives `2.2233`. Which is absolutely wrong. I use this also in one other place in which this works.

```
SUM(callers_total / (a.start_reached_speech_mobile + a.start_reached_speech_landline + a.start_reached_text + a.start_reached_email))
```

Really hope someone could clarify why this is going wrong because I really don't have a clue.

Comment: Quotient of sums is not the same as sum of quotients.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
SUM(callers_total) /
SUM(a.start_reached_speech_mobile + a.start_reached_speech_landline + a.start_reached_text + a.start_reached_email)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're summing up all the percentages, it looks like.  What happens if you get rid of the outer `SUM`?